# LinearLayout Row CheckBox retrieve

Tags: android, sqlite

Edit: Using a different method to display the data.

I'm currently able to display the data and ensure that there's no memory leakage or recycle of listview. In addition, I can change the colour of the text based on another column's data.

The onclick function to check the checkbox has also been completed.

However, i'm still lacking in one part. Which is getting the data after pressing the submit button. Can't seems to get the checkbox row by row.

```
public class EncounterActivity extends Activity {
        ListView list;
        TextView eid;
        TextView eclerkship;
        TextView ename;
        TextView etype;
        TextView erequiredattempts;


        // DATABASE ADAPTOR
        private eAndPDbAdapter encounterDB;
        private Context myContext = EncounterActivity.this;

        //arrayAdapter
        ListAdapter adapter;
        CheckBox cBox = null; 

        //Button Btngetdata;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> encountersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        //various layout
        ListView encounterList;

        static String value;
        private EditText filterText = null;

        private  Cursor mCursor; 

        String clerkShip = null; 

        //JSON Node Names 
        private static final String TAG_ENCOUNTERS = "encounters";
        private static final String TAG_E_ID = "e_id";
        private static final String TAG_E_CLERKSHIP = "clerkship";
        private static final String TAG_E_NAME = "encounter_name";  
        private static final String TAG_E_TYPE = "type";
        private static final String TAG_E_REQUIRED_ATTEMPTS = "required_attempts";

        //JSONArray android = null;


        private List nameList = new ArrayList(); 
        private List idList = new ArrayList(); 
        private List typeList = new ArrayList(); 
        public  List encounterSelected = new ArrayList();   

    public void displayList()
    {
          displaySharedPreferences();

        encounterDB = new eAndPDbAdapter(myContext);
        encounterDB.open();
        mCursor = encounterDB.retrieveAllEncounterCursor(clerkShip);
        if ((mCursor != null) && (mCursor.getCount() > 0)) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
            {
            do {

                String eID = mCursor.getString(1);
                String encounter_name = mCursor.getString(3);
                String encounter_type = mCursor.getString(4);
                this.idList.add(eID);
                this.nameList.add(encounter_name);
                this.typeList.add(encounter_type);

            }

            // move to the next row
            while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
        }
        encounterDB.close(); 

    }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_encounter);

            encountersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            displayList();
            LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.encounterslist);


            for(int i = 0 ; i<nameList.size();i++)
            {
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_v, null);
                final LinearLayout single = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.listV);
                single.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        LinearLayout nestedLL  = (LinearLayout) single.getChildAt(1);
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) nestedLL.getChildAt(0);
                        if(cb.isChecked())
                        {
                            cb.setChecked(false);
                            single.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cb.setChecked(true);
                            single.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);;
                        }
                    }
                });
                TextView ID = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.eid);
                TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ename);
                TextView type = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.etype);


                String nameValue = nameList.get(i).toString();
                String IDValue = idList.get(i).toString();
                String typeValue = typeList.get(i).toString(); 

                if (typeValue.equals("Must see"))
                {
                    name.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
                else
                {
                    name.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                }

                name.setText(nameValue);
                ID.setText(IDValue);
                parentLayout.addView(v);
            }
            myContext = this;

    };




    public void displaySharedPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(EncounterActivity.this);

        String listPrefs = prefs.getString("listpref", "No Clerkship Selected");

        StringBuilder builder2 = new StringBuilder();
        builder2.append(listPrefs);

    clerkShip = builder2.toString();

    }



    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView mProductNameTextView;
        public TextView mProductIdTextView;
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.encounter, menu);
    return true;

        }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_encounter_save:
            openEncounterSave();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            openSettings();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void openEncounterSave() {


    LinearLayout ListV =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.encounterslist);
    //Get the number of rows - Correct number of row. 
    int RowIndex = ListV.getChildCount();
         for(int i = 0 ; i<RowIndex;i++)
         {
             //Go through 1 row by 1 row. 
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_v, null);
                final LinearLayout single = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.listV);

                //Open the nested LinearLayout. 
                LinearLayout nestedLL  = (LinearLayout) single.getChildAt(1);

                //get the first item in the nested LinearLayout 
                //In this case it's the CheckBox. 
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) nestedLL.getChildAt(0);
                        boolean validation =  cb.isChecked();

                        if (validation == true)
                        {
                            String nameValue = nameList.get(RowIndex).toString();
                            Toast.makeText(myContext, nameValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            String IDValue = idList.get(RowIndex).toString();
                            encounterSelected.add(IDValue);
                         //Retrieve the ID value and add it into the EncouterSelected ArrayList. 
                        }

         }
         //Sort the array on order before sending it back to NewCases 
       Collections.sort(encounterSelected);
     StringBuilder full = new StringBuilder(); 
     String value =  full.append(encounterSelected).toString();

    //  Intent encounterIntent = new Intent();
    //  encounterIntent.putExtra("EncounterArray", value);
    //  setResult(-1, encounterIntent);
    //  finish();
    }

    public void openSettings() {
        Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(this, PrefsActivity.class);
        startActivity(settingsIntent);
    }

    }
```

EncounterActivity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">

         <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/encounterslist"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

List_V.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listV"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/listCheck"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false" >
    </CheckBox>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ename"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
                </LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/etype"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/erequiredattempts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show your logcat output.

Comment: post your stack trace here

Comment: @SilentKiller Sorry included.

Comment: getChildAt does not do what you think it does on a list view.

Comment: Also, you need to modify the underlying data, not the directly the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(EncounterActivity.this,encouterlist.get(+position).get("encounter_name") + " Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

What is this **+position?** Try to remove this Toast and check if it works. I think the problem is with this Toast. And try this

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.listCheck);
if (null != checkBox)    
    checkBox.setChecked(true);
```

Comment: Removed and nope. same issue. Still having multiple items on listview getting check and crashes.